# Library for creating C++ native application with GUI defined in XML?

Tags: c++, xml, user-interface, native, xul

I need a C++ library for creating stand-alone native application. The library should support creating GUI using XML tags. I've gotten some information about XUL of Mozilla but this XUL requires XULRunner to run the application.

The scenario is like this:

```
What I have:
(1) C++ code in .cpp files
(2) GUI defined in .xml files

The output I need:
A single stand-alone native application
```

Comment: Qt4 .ui files are just XML files.

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Comment: also the class of reference for this kind of approach under QT is http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html

Comment: any tutorials for creating Qt application GUI with .ui files?

Comment: @PaulDinh: See the comment right above yours.

Comment: well, you first have to understand how QT works, it's not a long road but loading UI files it's just as complex as understanding a single QT class ( by the way the calculator example shows you 1 way to do this, it's also included in the QTcreator SDK ). http://qt-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of testing, I got a conclusion. It's perfect to use Qt for the goal asked in question.

Qt offers a widget (aka control, aka GUI component) called QWebView that renders HTML5 using WebKit. We can use this QWebView together with QMainWindow to form a native-look-alike application.

Calling JS from C++ can be done this way:

```
QWebView Webview;
Webview->load(...);
...
Webview->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("alert('whatever');");
```

Calling C++ from JS can be done similarly:

```
//(1) in C++ code:
QWebView Webview; 
Webview->load(...);
QObject  Object; //or any object inherited from QObject
...
Webview->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Cpp",&Object);

//(2) in HTML/JS code:
<script>
Cpp.some_function(); //declared in the QObject above, with 'public slots:'
</script>
```

However, the result is hard to be a single binary file, because the application requires dynamic link library of Qt (Qt core, Qt gui, Qt network, Qt webkit, etc.). Building an installer can solve the problem.